# pybit error " Http status code is not 200. " when running session.query_kline

Tags: python, loops, cryptography, bybit, pybit

I have the code that I was using before to export the kline data from bybit.

```
for i in range(len(pairName)):
                              
        coinKline = session.query_kline(symbol=pairName[i], interval=str(sinceTime),  from_time=since)['result']
        time.sleep(0.05)
```

the works fine, but as I want to export multiple pairs kline in a loop, I am receving the error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\XXXXXXXX\OneDrive\algoTrading\coinbaseData\bybit\multiple_coin_check.py", line 95, in <module>
    coinKline = session.query_kline(symbol=pairName[i], interval=str(sinceTime), from_time=since)['result']
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\XXXXXXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\pybit\usdt_perpetual.py", line 30, in query_kline
    return self._submit_request(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\XXXXXXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\pybit\_http_manager.py", line 307, in _submit_request
    raise FailedRequestError(
pybit.exceptions.FailedRequestError: Http status code is not 200. (ErrCode: 429) (ErrTime: 14:10:00).
Request → GET https://api.bybit.com/public/linear/kline: {'symbol': 'BAKEUSDT', 'interval': '1', 'from': 1705402146}.
```

I should mention that before my whole script was working fine, but now it is throwing out this error.

Also, I have to say that, the error pops out for different "i" values; e.g., once it happens in i=3 (one pair) and another time i=12.

Thanks for you help!

I have thought that the problem might be caused by rate limits of bybit api, an I have change the timesleep as well (tried 1s even), but it didnt change anything.

Comment: Yep, code 429 is the rate limit.

Comment: actually I found the problem and was not rate limit.

the 200 value refers to the length of kline data, and as I was reading the data in loop, I was supposed to update the time every 1 minute, because if wouldnt do that, the 200 was being increased.

I have also placed a longer pause for the retry.